# Make a 2D tile map from isometric tile

Tags: unity, 2d, tiles

So I have an isometric tile ( PNG ) and I was wondering how can I make a 2d tile map from it. I am using Unity.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible. You just have to have some method of converting from 2D coordinates to 2.5 coordinates. Usually this is done using an isometric projection matrix like so: http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/interactive-svg-components/isometric-projection

This is the method that the isometric toolkits on the asset store use, like : https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/27851

and

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/33032

Another common method is to work in 3d space and just adjust the camera so that everything appears isometric.

Answer (score -1):

i don't think that's possible. AFAIK isometric is still just 2d just drawn from a different perspective. You'd have to draw the tiles again from the other perspective to change that